# I need help in find object by id in array nested in object

Tags: mongodb

```
school object :{
    "id":"school1"
    "adress":"aaaaa" 
    "studentInfo":{
        "details" : [ 
            {
                "class" : "a",
                "studentId" : "dan",
                "subject" : "math",

            },
            {
                "class" : "b",
                "studentId" : "ron",
                "subject" : "math",

            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I having a problem to get specific object from details array.
my desired result is to find by  studentId:

```
{
    "class" : "a",
    "studentId" : "dan",
    "subject" : "math",
}
```

I tried :

```
db.getCollection('schools').find(
    {'name':'school1'},
    {'studentInfo.details':{$elemMatch:{'studentId':'dan'} } }
)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: school1 is the value of 'id' attribute. Why are you searching by 'name'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is one way of doing it : below is the shell command:

```
db.schools.find({"id" : "school1", "studentInfo.details.studentId" :"dan"}, {"studentInfo.details.$" : 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.findOne({ studentId: "dan" })
```